# Gstreamer change source on PLAYING state

Tags: python, c, gstreamer

Hello guys I wanna know how can I switch between different sources in my pipeline without changing state for example if I have :

## Source 1

```
 filesrc location=file1 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

## Source 2

```
 filesrc location=file2 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

## Source 3

```
 filesrc location=file3 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I want to accomplish something like switching between channels on TV. Is it possible to change location property dynamically ? I searched over and over and didn't found anything specific.If you could point me to some code examples `C` or `python` I would be grateful.

Comment: Even if you change channels, the source remains same. The example you are talking about is different is like you are playing a movie from file1 and suddenly wants to play from file2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change filesrc location dynamically, alternatively you can change your logic a bit, Instead of filesrc use a fdsrc and write a separate application which reads data from your file1 and pumps to fdsrc's fd. so when you want to switch from file1 to file2/file3 you just need to tell your application to start pumping data from file2/file3 instead.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's not really the simplest solution. You can just create a GStreamer pipeline that outputs the streams one after another. See the "concat" element, playbin's gapless playback support, and the mixer elements for examples.

Comment: Alternatively just shut down the pipeline to READY state, change the source, go back to PLAYING. But that's not going to be gapless

Answer (score 1):

IMO your best bet is just to kill the old process and start a new one.

In a long running scenario on a diverse file set you'd be counting on a wide variety of GStreamer elements to reliably clean themselves up.